# Пауза цикла, когда инкремент равен определенному числу

Tags: c#

Я хочу делать паузу каждый раз, когда инкремент равен (N-1)+3,
т.е - 3,9,12,15 и т.д.

Как это сделать? (i += 3) Не подходит.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pages(); i++)
{
 ...
 Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: `if (i % 3 == 0) { Thread.Sleep(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) оператор.

```
if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
  Thread.Sleep(3000);
```